# cronjob on CentOS running a python script

Tags: python, cron

I wrote a Python script which I need it to run every 5 mins. My server is running `CentOS 6.4 Final`. Here's what I did in detail.

After logging into the server with an account has root access, I did `cd /var/spool/cron/`, I can see a couple of files has different usernames on it. Edit my file (the one has my username on it) with `nano myusername` and I added this line at the end of the file.

`*/5 * * * * /usr/bin/python /home/myusername/Dev/cron/python_sql_image.py`

I waited a bit and the cronjob works now. But new question: this Python code will generate a png file after being executed. When I manually run it, the png file will be created under the same folder with the py script, but when cronjob runs it, the png file was created on `/home/myusername`. Is there anyway I can change the location?

Comment: why not just use `crontab -e` ? I know some require a newline at the end of your crontab.

Comment: Check that the script is executable by the user running the cron daemon and also check if the daemon can read the file. And use `crontab -e` as suggested above :)

Comment: @C.B., `crontab -e` on CentOS is a bit weird. It looks like Vim but doesn't work as Vim does. When I want to quit, hitting Escape didn't work..

Comment: Then try with `EDITOR=/usr/bin/nano crontab -e` (maybe `yum install nano` before). Nano is far less powerful than vim, but more user-friendly.

Comment: OP, if you have another question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply change the working directory:

```
*/5 * * * * cd /home/myusername/Dev/cron && /usr/bin/python python_sql_image.py
```

Answer (score 0):

Each line that contains a job must end in a newline character.

Comment: This was plausible as an answer to the original question, however the poster then went and edited the question to be a substantially different one, something they really aren't supposed to do.

Comment: @ChrisStratton: roll it back to the previous version, and let the OP know what to do instead?